# WPF not updating UI

Tags: wpf, user-interface, dispatcher

I have tried many solutions how to update UI. I actually have some code in other projects which works and updates UI and in other projects it doesn't. It's very frustrating that even copy pasting simple code from blogs and stackoverflow answers which should work, it doesn't.

This one works in my another project but in my current one it does not work:

```
await System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => LoadingBar.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden));
```

This doesn't work also in both projects:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => this.LoadingBar.Value = value ), null);
```

I tried this one too and does not work.

```
  if (CheckAccess())
            {
            CreateProjectProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;
            CreateProjectProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
```

CheckAccess() returns true and still my progressbar does not update in UI.

Is there something Im missing in general? There must be because And if you have any great tutorial or blog for updating UI, please provide it. I've checked many blogs and copy pasted code as I said before and still not cant get it work.

These are code from my WPF projects so that's why there are different names. Im just looking way to get it update for sure.

Update:

Progressbar does get visible but IsIndeterminate does not make it progressbar to progress. Im guessing that code after updating is freezing UI. Im going to change functions to be async methods and see if UI is not freezed anymore. I'll update this tomorrow.

Comment: Invoking delegates on the GUI thread is a generally useful (required, even) and widespread technique, used by countless programs successfully on a daily basis. If in your case you cannot get this common technique to work, then you will need to post a reasonably concise-but-complete code example that demonstrates your exact problem. If you expect a useful answer, that is.

Comment: Okay hmm. I think im in a right track. What if there are codes(after dispatcher.invoke codeline), they are run in a different thread. Does it freezes UI which is why it looks like UI is not updated or progressbar is not running?

Comment: And which you prefere I should use and in which cases, BeginInvoke or Invoke? What are the conditions is prefered to use and when? Could you write an answer of this

Comment: In general, I prefer BeginInvoke() due to the lack of deadlock potential. You would use Invoke() when for some reason you need the current thread to not continue execution until the operation being invoked has completed. As for your "freezing UI", again...without a good code example, there's little way to know what's going on.

Comment: Okay thanks. I have a createProject event called after dispatcher code which im suspecting to freeze UI. I'm gonna make that function to async and see it that's the case for freezing and dispather code was right all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Question... Why would you want to use an Async method to fire a visibility thing?  I wouldn't do that, rather if I had an async job, I would wait until it joined the main thread or as I used to do in the old days I'd fire an event.  The event handler (running) on the main thread would do the visibility stuff.  I can't tell you why it isn't working other than this thought, perhaps the current dispatcher isn't on the main GUI thread?

Comment: I have async methods because I want certain things to be completed without freezing UI. Like listview being generated and you can still interact with UI.

Comment: BeginInvoke is AYSNC and INVOKE is not.  Y

Comment: Sorry I didn't make myself clear, whenever anything is queued up on the dispatcher thread it is either through Invoke (do it synchronously) or BeginInvoke (asynchronously)  My point was that if you have a long outstanding job, I typcially always do that on non GUI threads and allow the natural marshalling process of those other non GUI Threads to make the GUI updates.  However your pattern is ok, and you are correct that something else in pgm. could be holding up the GUI.  I tend to stay away from dispatcher queing simply because I never know when it will get around to it.